# перенос сайта на платформе yii на opensrver

Tags: php, mysql

перенес сайт на локальный хостинг openserver. подключил бд, пути.
Выходит такая ошибка

Fatal error: Call to a member function asCMenuArray() on a non-object in D:\OpenServer\domains\azimut_dev\themes\utasan\views\layouts\main.php on line 246
В самом файле ошибок нет

Строчки кода, куда он ругается

```
<?php    
Yii::import('application.modules.store.models.StoreCategory');
$items = StoreCategory::model()->findByPk(1)->asCMenuArray();
if(isset($items['items']))
{
    $this->widget('application.extensions.mbmenu.MbMenu',array(
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'catalog-menu', 'id'=>'nav'),
            'items'=>$items['items'])
    );
}
```

?>

Comment: Это значит `findByPk(1)` ничего не вернул и `asCMenuArray` применять не к чему. а не на опен сервере когда был проект - не ругался потому, что было наверное отключено вывод ошибок. А еще версия php другая... хотя версия особо на это не должно повлиять... просто надо было раньше отображение ошибок включать) и проверять на то, что реально данные вернулись

Comment: почему тогда на боевом сервере всё работает?

Comment: потому что на боевом отключены `error_reporting` полагаю. как я  упомянул выше

Comment: что мне сейчас конкретно нужно сделать?

Comment: я пробывал отключить вывод ошибок,но проблему это не решило

Comment: `findByPk(1)` ничего не вернул и `asCMenuArray` применять не к чему. надо проверять на то, что реально данные вернулись

Comment: Вы сможете мне помочь в этом?

Answer (score 1):

Вам подсказали в комментариях, что `findByPk(1)` возвращает `null`, а не объект, в котором можно вызвать метод `asCMenuArray()`. Поэтому, сначала необходимо проверить, что возвращает `findByPk(1)`. Как вариант:

```
<?php    
Yii::import('application.modules.store.models.StoreCategory');
$model = StoreCategory::model()->findByPk(1);
$items = (!empty($model)?$model->asCMenuArray():array());
if(isset($items['items']))
{
    $this->widget('application.extensions.mbmenu.MbMenu',array(
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'catalog-menu', 'id'=>'nav'),
            'items'=>$items['items'])
    );
}
```

Comment: он возвращает главную страницу страницы

Comment: Кто, куда возвращает?